# Node.js: Send new request with token(JWT) in URL after logging in

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt, body-parser

After the user has logged in and generated a token, I want to send it automatically in the header or something similar.

So far I managed to generate the token, and check if it exists and if it's valid, it seems to work fine as long as I copy paste it the url as "?token = generated token".

I wasn't able to understand how to send it without writing it myself in the URL of Postman.

I'm using these modules:

- Express
- Body-parser
- Mongoose
- JsonWebToken

So I'm curious if it's ok that I choose to generate the token only at the login of if I need to add it in the user's Schema.

I don't want to use Passport for now because I want to understand the basics first.

After searching for a while (the jwt documentation included) I didn't really managed to find something that I can understand and implement.

So here I am, if someone could guide me in the right direction, that'd be great.

***Sorry for the bad indentation and thanks in advance.***

Here is some code:

**jwt-middleware.js**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = 'mySecret';
module.exports = function  (req, res, next) {
var token = req.body.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.query.token;

if(!token) {
    return res.status(404).send({error:'No token found'});
} else {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decode) {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).send({error:'Invalid token'});
        } else {
           // req.decode =  decode;
           decode = jwt.decode(token, {complete:true});
           //console.log(req.headers);
          // req.headers.authorization = token;
          // console.log(req.headers.authorization);
            console.log(decode.header);
            console.log(decode.payload);
            next();
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

**routes/user.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
    var verifyToken = require('../config/jwt-middleware');
    var secret = 'mySecret';


     //Import models
     var User = require('../models/users');


  router.get('/', verifyToken, function (req, res) {
      User.find({}, function (err, storedUsers) {
          if (err) {
              return res.status(500).send({ error: 'No users found' });
          } else {
              return res.status(200).send(storedUsers);
          }
      });

  });


  router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
      User.find().lean().exec(function (err, doc) {
          for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
              if (req.body.username == doc[i].username && req.body.password == doc[i].password) {
                  var token = jwt.sign({username:req.body.username}, secret, {expiresIn:'1h'});
                  return res.status(200).send('You\'re now logged in ' + 'with the username: ' + doc[i].username + ' and password: ' + doc[i].password + ' \nJSON token: \n' + token);
             }
          }
                 return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Invalid username or password: ' + req.body.username });
      });
  });
```

**Some screenshots:**

[No token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xg1R.jpg)

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylDg.jpg)

[Manually inserted token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVjHy.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a case where you're trying to send the token as a header with the `x-access-token` key and it's failing?  I'm also not clear if your question is, "how do I get the token for verification without using the querystring?" or "should I put the token in the user's schema?"

Comment: As an aside, it looks like you're implementing your User without any form of password hashing.  I hope you understand that this is a terrible idea, and you're only doing it for the first cut while you figure out JWTs?

Comment: Also, while I'm at it, if you're using the async version of `jwt.verify()` (which you are), then the `decoded` param to your callback *is* the decoded token, you don't need to run the token through `jwt.decode()` to get it.

Comment: Hey,  I will use bcryptjs for password hashing later one, as for now, there is no need to hash it.  Regarding the first question, I'm not sure if I need to add a token to the user schema, was asking because I saw some examples.  And I don't know how exactly to send `x-access-token` to the header tried something along the lines of `response.writeHead(statusCode, [reasonPhrase], [headers])`, but deleted it.

Comment: From postman, just click on the Headers tab and add it. Too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I'll try and answer your question even though I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking.  The basic flow of a JWT is that the user logs in, and you issue it.  You don't store it because the whole point of a JWT is that there's no overhead on the server for storing it (allowing for a more distributed approach to user management).  The exception is if you want to do a logout feature, but that doesn't look like it's one of your requirements.

From the standpoint of responsibilities, you should have a Login function or module which is responsible for verifying a user's credentials and issuing a token.  You should have a Verification function or module that validates the token and places the decoded token on the request object for later use (no need to repeatedly decode).  And you may (or may not) have an Authorization module that validates that a given user is allowed to perform a given task.

So, from the top. Note that you can let the DB do the query work rather than doing your own loop. I'm also assuming that your User schema will include a verifyPassword method that takes care of comparing salted and hashed passwords.

```
// login
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
      // note I didn't use lean() because I want access to User methods. Performance is less of an issue in my version, b/c the DB is only retrieving one user at most. 
      User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec(function (err, user) {
          if(err) return next(err); 
          if(!user) return res.status(401).send();
          if (user.verifyPassword(req.body.password)) {
                  // maybe add more info about the user, like display name
                  var token = jwt.sign({username:user.username}, secret, {expiresIn:'1h'});
                  return res.status(200).send({message: 'You are now signed in', token: token});
             }
          }
                 return res.status(404).send({ error: 'Invalid username or password: ' + req.body.username });
      });
  });
```

Now the client will have access to the token more easily, and can send it on further requests.

```
// verify
module.exports = function  (req, res, next) {
  // this is fine, though I think the standard is that the token should be sent in the Authorization header with the format Bearer {token}
  var token = req.body.token || req.headers['x-access-token'] || req.query.token;

  if(!token) {
    return next(); // this middleware just is responsible for decoding, other middleware checks authorization
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err, decode) {
        if(err) {
            return next(); // again, a bad token doesn't necessarily mean anything for some application pages, put the logic elsewhere. 
        } else {
            req.user = decode; // this will be { username } based on above
            req.token = token; // generally you don't need it but just in case. 
            next();
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

Ok, so now further middleware will include a req.user that you can use to check if a given user should be allowed to see a resource or not.  For example:

```
function userRequired(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send({message: 'You must be logged in to view this page' });
  return next();
}
```

This scales well to other checks, you could have one for various roles, etc.